# Database building for a Flask App

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on Flask app and I could make my initial app running. That app was taking up data from an existing database (coming from a PHP app) so I just wrote models around the database.

Now the team has decided to do some major change to the schema for next version of app. I understand that the schema can be created as objects and migrations are possible using Alembic (for SQLAlchemy).

My question is: shall I be following this route or write the build and migration scripts directly in `SQL` as I read that some times ORM tools are not able to generate optimal Query and also the migration tool can't always understand the database changes as intended (i.e. renaming a table from A to B can be understood as dropping table A and creating table B)?